# highcharts callback functions retuning error object undefined

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, callback

I am trying to remove the gridlines in highcharts but leave the x and y axes labels. I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: obj.options.xAxis[1] is undefined` message using the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; }
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[43] = function(obj){

obj.options.xAxis[0].labels = true,
obj.options.yAxis[0]= {labels: true}
}
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with a sample data on some online editor that I could work on?